# MySQL Remote Access from anywhere

Tags: mysql, workbench

I want to create my own RDBMS server with remote access, which I can access and query from any computer over the internet connecting using ip address of my host pc. I installed MySQL edited `my.cnf` and commented the bind-address and then using MySQL Workbench connected to 127.0.0.1 i queried grant all ip address for all the databases.Then i tried connecting from another pc with my host ip address.But unfortunately it didn't connected.I even opened port through firewall but still. It didn't work. M now a lot messed up.Can you please help me to guide how do i start to create my own RDBMS server which I can access from anywhere. Or any guide. I basically want to host MySQL on my ip address which can be accessed from anywhere.

P.S. Please don't tell me about security flaws it can have.I totally considered and understood it. M trying to make project for my college.And security is not at all an issue as i have a separate old PC for server.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps something better asked/searched for over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: It is still probably something with your firewall. Had the same problem with mine so I turned off the firewall to test and it connected.

Comment: Try putting the server in your router's DMZ.

Answer (score 3):

If your issue is not able to remotely connect to MySQL, then try below steps. I had the same issue and got it resolved by performing below commands.

1) `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

2) `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1`     // comment this line out

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0          //add this line just below above line
```

3) `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`  //restart mysql

4) `sudo mysql -u root -p`          //login to mysql cli as user 'root'

5) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'beta' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Here 'root' is the mysql user and 'beta' is the password and here privileges are set for 'root'.Change it accordingly and execute above query in mysql cli.

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

If in

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

It has the following line

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Then make the changes in

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```